# docker ubuntu container: shell linked to bash still starts shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, docker

Alright guys, so I try to install rvm in a docker container based on ubuntu:14.04. During the process, I discovered that some people do something like this to ensure docker commands are also run with the bash:

```
RUN ln -fs /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Now The weirdness happens and I hope someone of you can explain it to me:

```
→ docker run -it --rm d81ff50de1ce /bin/bash
root@e93a877ab3dc:/# ls -lah /bin
....
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Mar  1 16:15 sh -> /bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Mar  1 16:15 sh.distrib -> /bin/bash
...
root@e93a877ab3dc:/# /bin/sh
sh-4.3# echo $0
/bin/sh
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? I know I could just prefix my commands in the dockerfile w/ `bash -c`, but I would like to understand what is happening here and if possible still ditch the `bash -c` prefix in the dockerfile.

Thanks a lot,
Robin

Answer (score 2):

It's because bash has a compatibility mode where it tries to emulate `sh` if it is started via the name `sh`, as the manpage says:

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
>   behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while
>   conforming to the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an
>   interactive login  shell, or a non-interactive shell with the --login
>   option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from
>   /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order.  The --noprofile option
>   may be used to inhibit this behavior.  When invoked as an interactive
>   shell with the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its
>   value if it is defined, and uses the expanded value as the name of a
>   file to read  and  execute.   Since  a  shell  invoked as sh does not
>   attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup files, the
>   --rcfile option has no effect.  A non-interactive shell invoked with the name sh does not attempt to read any other startup files.  When
>   invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are
>   read.